# windows 10 how to change password

Tags: windows-10

I created a local user account which worked just fine, but recently when I tried to use some feature that required microsoft account, my local PC account turned to something weird. Now I don't see my name at login screen but my e-mail and I have to use different password than I had for my local PC.

The option "Change password" disappeared from CTRL + ALT + DEL screen. How can I change this password? Do I have to use microsoft site for this since now forever? Their site has some weird password policies that I don't want to use for my OWN LOCAL pc. I don't care about password security. Can I change it to something else that isn't stored on microsoft servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You converted your account to a Microsoft account. You can convert it back to a local account by going to Settings - Accounts and remove your Microsoft account from there.

After this you will not automatically have any access to applications that require Microsoft account, but you can usually log in separately. Just be careful what you select next time.